# Cannot render express-handelbars template

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

I'm new to node and having difficulty to get a  simple `express-handlebar` to render a static html page:

```
require('./config/config');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');

const _ = require('lodash');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const {ObjectID} = require('mongodb');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');


var {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose');
var {Todo} = require('./models/todo');
var {User} = require('./models/user');
var {authenticate} = require('./middleware/authenticate');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io =socketIO(server);


const port = process.env.PORT;
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, './public');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', exphbs);
app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.get('/', (req, res) => { 
      res.render('index');
    });
```

Instead of `index.html` sitting in `views` folder, I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'function exphbs(config) {
    return create(config).engine;
}'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at new View (/home/me/nodechatapp/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:81:14)
    at Function.render (/home/me/nodechatapp/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/me/nodechatapp/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at app.get (/home/me/nodechatapp/server.js:37:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/me/nodechatapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/me/nodechatapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/me/nodechatapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/me/nodechatapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/me/nodechatapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/me/nodechatapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/me/nodechatapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at SendStream.error (/home/me/nodechatapp/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:121:7)
```

What could be wrong here? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are missing the `app.engine()` call in your server set up. Based on the [docs](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars) you need:

`app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');`

You already use `app.set` for the view engine, but I think you need to call the prior line.

Comment: Well, now I get `Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/home/me/nodechatapp/views"`. Any hint abou this?

Comment: Yeah... I think that it's looking for a file named `index.handlebars` at `nodechatapp/views` so the full path would be `nodechatapp/views/index.handlebars`. Does that file exist?

Comment: No. Actually it was `index.html`. But changing the extension fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: The reason it's looking for the `index.handlebars` file there is because that's the directory you set for your `views` and lower down you define that all traffic routed to `/` will result in an attempt to render `index` from your views directory. The reason it's a `.handlebars` file is because you set express-handlebars as the view engine.

Comment: Is there a way to use `.html` instead? I really hate to have a `.handlebars` extension!

Comment: Unfortunately the express-handlebars view engine will only properly work with `.handlebars` extensions. I'm not too familiar with express-handlebars specifically, but that's how other view engines such as `jade` or regular `handlebars` work. It will render out to `.html` though, so only you as the developer will see the `.handlebars` extension.

Comment: Well I could settled with `.hbs` using `app.engine('hbs', exphbs({layoutsDir: layoutsDir}));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');`